# Basis of topological space

Tags: general-topology

> **Theorem.** Let $(X, \mathcal{G})$ a topological space.
>
> $(i)$ Let $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$ a basis of $(X,\mathcal{G})$. Then,
>
> $(a)$ $\mathcal{B}$ is a coverage of $X$;
>
> $(b)$ for each $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$, $B_1\cap B_2\ne\emptyset$ and for each $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.
>
> $(ii)$ Let $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ a family of nonempty set for which they are valid $(a)$ and $(b)$, then exists a unique topology $\mathcal{G}$ on $X$ of which $\mathcal{B}$ is basis.

**Question.** Let the family set
$$
\tilde{I}:=\{(a,b)\;|\;-\infty<a<b<+\infty\}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})
$$
How do you verify that this family checks the properties $(a)$ and $(b)$? Thanks!

Comment: What's your difficulty in that?

Comment: @BerciMy difficulty is to strictly prove that those properties are true. With examples I can understand that they are true, but I do not know if it should be prove

Comment: An example is not a proof.

Comment: @William Elliot Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove (a), assume we are given an $x\in\Bbb R$. Can you write up a basis element that contains $x$? 
To prove (b), assume $x$ is in both intervals $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$. Then consider the following positive numbers:
$$L:=\min(x-a_1,\,x-a_2),\ \ \ R:=\min(b_1-x,\,b_2-x)$$
Or, take directly $a:=\max(a_1,a_2), \ b:=\min(b_1,b_2)$.

Comment: For $\epsilon>0$ fixed $x\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Yes, for instance $x\in (x-1,x+1)$

Comment: In this case the base is even closed under finite intersections (when the intersection is non-empty).